# Anti-Derivative of $\ln(x^2 + 7)$ is kicking my butt, can anyone help?

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm given $\ln(x^2 + 7)$ in a problem and to solve it I need to get the anti-derivative, but I haven't been able to properly calculate it.

Could someone show me how to obtain this anti-derivative? It would be a major help to me.

Comment: Start by differentiating $x\ln(x^2+7)$.

Comment: how would I go about that?

Comment: Product rule and chain rule.

Comment: Investigate $\int \ln x $ first.

Answer (score 6):

Start with [integration by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts):
$$\int \ln(x^2+7) \,\mbox{d}x = x\ln(x^2+7) \color{blue}{- \int \frac{2x^2}{x^2+7} \,\mbox{d}x}$$
And then (long division, or this trick):
$$\frac{2x^2}{x^2+7} =2\frac{x^2\color{green}{+7-7}}{x^2+7} = 2-\frac{14}{x^2+7}$$
So:
$$\int \ln(x^2+7) \,\mbox{d}x = x\ln(x^2+7) \color{blue}{- 2x + 14 \underbrace{\int \frac{1}{x^2+7} \,\mbox{d}x}_{\to \arctan \ldots}}$$
Can you take it from there?

---

If you don't know and/or can't use a standard integral for that last part, here are a few steps to do it 'manually':
$$\int \frac{1}{x^2+7} \,\mbox{d}x = \frac{1}{7}\int \frac{1}{\frac{x^2}{7}+1} \,\mbox{d}x = \frac{1}{7}\int \frac{1}{\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{7}}\right)^2+1} \,\mbox{d}x$$
and then choose $u = x/\sqrt{7}$ so $\mbox{d}x = \sqrt{7}\,\mbox{d}u$:
$$\int \frac{1}{x^2+7} \,\mbox{d}x = \frac{\sqrt{7}}{7}\int \frac{1}{u^2+1} \,\mbox{d}u = \frac{\sqrt{7}}{7} \arctan u + C \to \ldots$$
and switch back to $x$.

Comment: So how would the end result look you mentioned arctan.

Comment: You mean you don't know how to do the last integral? If needed, I can edit and elaborate but it's standard (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_rational_functions#Miscellaneous_integrands); second one).

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm in highschool and am not the quickest learner, if you could expand it would be a major help.

Comment: I added a bit for that last integral.

Comment: so the end result is $x\ln(x^2 + 7) - 2x + 14 (\sqrt(7)/7)arctan(x)+C$

Comment: Almost, not $\arctan x$ but $\arctan u = \arctan \frac{x}{\sqrt{7}}$ and I would also simplify $14\sqrt{7}/7$ to $2\sqrt{7}$.

Comment: so it's x ln(x^2 + 7) -2x + 2 sqrt(7) arctan(x/ sqrt(7))

Comment: Correct - but don't forget the constant of integration ;-).

Answer (score 0):

Factoring the quadratic, we can write $\ln(x^2+7)=\ln(x+i\sqrt{7})+\ln(x-i\sqrt{7})$. But $\int\ln x\,dx=x\ln x-\int x\cdot \frac1x dx=x\ln x-x$, and from this formula we can deduce the antiderivatives of both terms.

Comment: $x^2+7 \neq (x+\sqrt{7})(x-\sqrt{7})$.

Comment: @wythagoras Well, that's embarrassing. Fixed.

Comment: How does introducing $i$ help? I don't think you get an useful answer form this.

Comment: It lets you split up the logarithm into $\log(x-x_0)$ terms, which can be integrated by parts directly. All that remains is to recombine the resulting antiderivatives. (To that end it's probably useful to note that $\arctan(z)=\frac{i}{2}\left[\ln (1-i z)-\ln(1+i z)\right]$). @wythagoras